# How to resolve xsd schemas in appplicationContext.xml?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I try to create srping application from idea with 3 modules:
Structure of project is

aggregator
   |_core
   |_parent

In every module there are pom.xml 
I added spring dependencies in project, why idea shows red lines with can't found error message?

[image: applicationContext.xml]

Comment: don't worry about them, these are not important, as long as you can use their corresponding tags by successfully running you application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding dependecy by hand in child module.